# Vuejs function in mounted lifecycle hook

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I would like my `hideMe()` function to be called during the `mounted` lifecycle hook in my Vuejs code. Currently it is not, and I don't understand why.

My code is below:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      show: "initial"
    }
  }, 
  methods: {
    hideMe() {
     if(this.$vuetify.breakpoint.name == 'xs') {
        console.log("When is this rendered? " + this.$vuetify.breakpoint.name == 'xs');
        this.show = "none";
     }
   }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.hideme();
    console.log("This is a breakpoint name " + this.$vuetify.breakpoint.name);
    console.log(this.show);
  },
  computed: {
    imageHeight () {
     switch (this.$vuetify.breakpoint.name) {
       case 'xs': return '450px';
       case 'sm': return '500px';
       case 'md': return '500px';
       case 'lg': return '540px';
       case 'xl': return '540px';
     }
   }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is correct, try:

```
  methods: {
    hideMe() {
     if(this.$vuetify.breakpoint.name == 'xs') {
        console.log("When is this rendered? " + this.$vuetify.breakpoint.name == 'xs');
        this.show = "none";
     }
   }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.hideMe();
    console.log("This is a breakpoint name " + this.$vuetify.breakpoint.name);
    console.log(this.show);
  },
```

**Note:** The statement:

```
 console.log("When is this rendered? " + this.$vuetify.breakpoint.name == 'xs');
```

Will simply print `false` because it is working like

```
 console.log( ("When is this rendered? " + this.$vuetify.breakpoint.name) == 'xs');
```

Fix it adding `()`s:

```
 console.log("When is this rendered? " + (this.$vuetify.breakpoint.name == 'xs'));
```

Comment: Wow.. I can't tell what the difference is! Ha.. what's the secret because it works!

Comment: I made a new note in the answer. Another problem. Ah, and the problem with the "hideme" function is that you were calling `this.hideme()` and not `this.hideMe()` (notice the `M`)

Comment: Hah, yeah... don't forget to take a break sometimes :D